# How to replicate Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL data to an external on-premise PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've gotten a case that I need to replicate data from Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL to an external on-premise PostgreSQL DB. I've read the document and found that Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL does not support external replication yet. I've tried to search for a solution on the internet but was unlucky to find one. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? 3rd party solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is indeed [not yet supported](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-external-replica). Until it is, one workaround would be to schedule exports at regular intervals to a storage solution, and then import the dumps to the on-premise database. Here is how:

1- [Create a Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) into which the export dumps will be stored

2- [Create a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/) which will [connect to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions) and coordinate the [export operation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting#posgressqldump) to the Cloud Storage bucket

3- [Use Cloud Scheduler to configure the Cloud Function to trigger at regular intervals](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub#create_a_job)

4- Use your desired method for importing the regular dumps to the on-premise database